# Disk [test-s3] does not have not have a configured drivers

Tags: amazon-web-services, laravel-9, laravel-filesystem, aws-s3-client

Storage::disk('test-s3')->put($fileName, fopen($file_s3, 'rb')); throws error Disk [test-s3] does not have not have a configured drivers3s Below is the file system configuration `'disks' => [ 'test-s3'=> [ 'driver' => 's3', 'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'), 'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'), 'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION'), 'bucket' => 'test-s3', ] ]`

Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/filesystem#s3-driver-configuration

Comment: tried most of the options but no luck